# Laravel 5.4: User model relationships depending on a role

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to ask for the best strategy in this case (with MySQL DB):

I got a User Model/Table. A User can be of 3 different types: Admin, Owner and Worker.

- The Owner hasMany Locations
- The Location hasMany Workers
- The Worker belongsTo a Location

**1st Option I see:**

Does it make sense for the Owner and Worker to extends User Model since they have common fields and to add 'role' field in User table?

Is it correct to create 2 other tables for the Owner and Worker?

How Eloquent will handle relationships in this case?

**2nd option (easier but...):**

Admin, Owner, Worker are 3 different models/tables

---

Then i'd like to do get data like:

- **$location->owner()** // get user with a role of 'owner' for this location
- **$location->workers()** // get users with role of 'workers' for this location
- **$owner->workers()** // get the workers related to an owner

Comment: i would say keep single user table, and take roles middle table for belongsToMany relationship that way when in future if user can have many roles it will be handled. and you can defined location and worker belongsTo relationship on user model it self no problem in that, it will return null if that relation doesn't have data for other role.

Comment: Thanks but then how to set up models in order to do : $location->workers() or $owner->workers() ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i used:

- users table
- roles table
- role_user pivot table
- location table
- location_user pivot table

in User model, some queryScope methods to retrieve users by role:

```
public function scopeOwners($query) 
    {
        $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
            $q->where('name','owner');
        });
    }
```

easy enough.